# Using MVVM to enter a value in one 'Form' that is to be used in another 'Form' /MVVM'

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I am relatively new to Xamarin, and I am beginning to understand the concept of xaml forms and Model Views.

Is it possible to have one form to have a ViewModel which has several fields/properties and also a 'search' button that goes to a search 'Form' and then from the search 'Form' to a ListView 'Form', select from that ListView 'Form' and 'Go Back' to the first form and populate a field with what was selected from the ListView 'Form'?.

Can this be done with binding, if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples